# Android - "The following classes could not be found: - (Change to com.example.random.ScrollViewExt, Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)"

Tags: java, android, xml

I have extended the ScrollView class to create a class so that  can listen for the onScroll event. But it says that the class which i have extended cannot be found. I have tried the options given and none of them seem to work. Here is the code for the XML

```
   <com.example.random.ScrollViewExt
   android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </com.example.random.ScrollViewExt>
```

And here is the code for the custom class.

```
    package com.example.random;

    import android.widget.ScrollView;
    import android.content.Context;
     import android.util.AttributeSet;


    public class ScrollViewExt extends ScrollView {
        private ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener = null;
        public ScrollViewExt(Context context) {
              super(context);
         }

         public ScrollViewExt(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
              super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        public ScrollViewExt(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        } 

         public void setScrollViewListener(ScrollViewListener scrollViewListener) {
             this.scrollViewListener = scrollViewListener;
        } 

        @Override
         protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
            super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
             if (scrollViewListener != null) {
                 scrollViewListener.onScrollChanged(this, l, t, oldl, oldt);
              }
          }
     }
```

Any idea on what I could do?

Comment: what is scrollview listener here??

Comment: It is an interface. Which is implemented in MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<ScrollView></ScrollView>` in the XML file, then cast the object to `ScrollViewExt` in order to handle its listener

```
<ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The interface for listener

```
public interface ScrollViewListener {
    void onScrollChanged(ScrollViewExt scrollView, 
                         int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy);
}
```

Then make activity class implement the interface created before, and then:

```
scroll = (ScrollViewExt) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
scroll.setScrollViewListener(this);
```

Also

```
@Override
public void onScrollChanged(ScrollViewExt scrollView, int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
    // We take the last son in the scrollview
    View view = (View) scrollView.getChildAt(scrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
    int diff = (view.getBottom() - (scrollView.getHeight() + scrollView.getScrollY()));

    // if diff is zero, then the bottom has been reached
    if (diff == 0) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helped. Fascinated with you guys. Never thought i could expect a reply this early. :D

Comment: This is StackOverFlow :)